# How to get jquery jScrollPane and jscrollHorizontalPane plugins working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a div where I must have both vertical and horizontal scrollbars stylized. I'm already using jScrollPane by Kelvin Luck. But I would like to integrate it with jscrollHorizontalPane, a mod based on the first.

Has anyone able to make them work together? Any other suggestion will be very welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to! Just use jScrollPane version 2 which provides both horizontal and vertical scrolling:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/